# use only input for change image without submit

Tags: php, html, input

I want use that form for change image but without click to submit.

```
<form action="chav.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" > 
    <label for="fileup"><img src="/images/img-ico.png"/>Aggiungi Foto</label>
    <input type="file" name="fileup" id="fileup" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="Upload" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo milldigital_filter('get',$_REQUEST['pg']); ?>" name="pg" /> 
</form>
```

so when i select image, directly submit without press any button.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit form using javascript within form event attribute `onchange`:

```
...
<input type="file" name="fileup" id="fileup" onchange="this.form.submit()" />
...
```

When browser render form element with `onchange` property it starts to observe if its value changes and execute javascript code when it does. It changes when you select file. [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onchange.asp)

`this.form` means we'll refer to form object that *this* html (form) element belongs to. Then execute its [submit()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp) method.

Comment: can you explain code of js ? or onChange do all work ?

Comment: @Mill I added some explanation although you can read this code in plain english. I don't think that this site is to provide google searching services either.

Comment: ok but this site is for help for code ^^ ,    so hidden submit and onchange to that